# Remote Push Notifications Swift

Tags: ios, swift, уведомления, swift4, push-уведомления

Приложение генерирует токен, отправляет на сервер, которое регистрирует его у себя. Потом сервер высылает на токен сообщение и тут задача мобильного приложения перехватить это сообщение и в зависимости от контента вставить изображение. Можно ли это сделать в методах фреймворка `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` в `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)` или надо обязательно создавать расширение `NotificationService`? И если можно обойтись малой кровью, то как это сделать? Вот метод, проблема что этот completionHandler вызывает метод бесконечно, а без него сообщение не показывается когда приложение активно. Буду рада любой подсказке, новичок в Swift, пока еще только пытаюсь разобраться. Заранее всем спасибо!

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let notificationContent = notification.request.content
        let modifiedNotificationRequest = createMyNotificationRequest(from: notificationContent)
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

        center.add(modifiedNotificationRequest) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to send notification \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completionHandler(.alert)
            }
        }
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите другой метод:

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

userInfo

A dictionary that contains information related to the remote notification, potentially including a badge number for the app icon, an alert sound, an alert message to display to the user, a notification identifier, and custom data.